# Excel - AVERAGEIFS with OR conditions?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

I'm trying to calculate a percentage value which uses an AVERAGEIFS function. Not quite sure how to describe it without context, so here's what I'm working with (minus 100+ rows of data):

[image: what I'm working with]

I've made the function look in column D for values of "W" and column C for values of "Cache" (`=AVERAGEIFS(L6:L205,D6:D205,"W",C6:C205,"Cache"`). I was hoping there was a way to make this function look for values of "W" or "R" in column D, instead of just "W".

I tried writing: `=AVERAGEIFS(L6:L205,D6:D205,"W",C6:C205,"Cache")+AVERAGEIFS(L6:L205,D6:D205,"R",C6:C205,"Cache")`
But this just added the two percentages together, instead of considering boths rows which contain "W", or "R".

I also tried adding OR between the functions (instead of the +) with a variety of bracket combinations, but excel wasn't a fan of that.

If anyone has any suggestions or solutions to this I'd be grateful!

Comment: Calculate different AVERAGEIFS for different conditions and AVERAGE them like this `=AVERAGE(AVERAGEIFS(L6:L8,D6:D8,"W",C6:C8,"Cache"),AVERAGEIFS(L6:L8,D6:D8,"R",C6:C8,"Cache"))`

Comment: This just gave me #VALUE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AVERAGE is defined as SUM/COUNT.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(L6:L205, D6:D205, {"R","W"}, C6:C205,"Cache"))/SUM(COUNTIFS(D6:D205, {"R","W"}, C6:C205,"Cache"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add new column with:

```
=IF(OR(D6="W";D6="R");TRUE)
```

and then use it in your formula.

Or other way try this:

```
=(SUMIFS(L6:L205,D6:D205,"W",C6:C205,"Cache")+SUMIFS(L6:L205,D6:D205,"R",C6:C205,"Cache"))/(COUNTIFS(D6:D205,"W",C6:C205,"Cache")+COUNTIFS(D6:D205,"R",C6:C205,"Cache"))
```

Comment: Excel gives me #NAME? from this

Comment: I have excel with other languages and can't try formula in my computer, but i think, I repaired it: =(SUMIFS(L6:L205,D6:D205,"W",C6:C205,"Cache")+SUMIFS(L6:L205,D6:D205,"R",C6:C205,"Cache"))/(COUNTIFS(D6:D205,"W",C6:C205,"Cache")+COUNTIFS(D6:D205,"R",C6:C205,"Cache"))

Comment: I think this might have worked, just trying to figure out of the number it has given me is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Consider curly brace around multiple items:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(L6:L205, D6:D205, {"W","R"}, C6:C205, "Cache")
```

Comment: This gives me a number, but it's lower than it should be, is that maybe down to the way AVERAGEIFS calculates it?